# How do i use google forms using an api in Angular2/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, api, firebase, google-forms

My App has two **Roles** one is **advertiser** and the other one is **user**, the advertiser used to create surveys on the basis of age groups,gender and interest of the user, *the point is that i wanna use google forms in my app because advertiser can create custom forms a/c to his campaign,so if the user fills the form up how do i get the **response data** via an **API**?* also i want to receive the **acknowledgement** that the form has been filled by the user so the user may have the reward for filling up the form.
btw i am using **firebase** as database